# check radio button android style inccorect

Tags: android, radio-button

My problem is very strange...

When i do a :

```
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```

the style of the radioButton "simple" in the screenshot is inccorect the inside of the radio button is not colored...

my xml is basic :

```
                     <RadioButton
                                android:text="Simple"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/radioButtonFenetresSimple"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:tag="1"
                                android:checked="false" />
```

result when setChecked :
[image: sample radio button problem]

Have you get this problem ?

thank's

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
RadioButton simple;
simple= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFenetresSimple);
simple.setChecked(true);
simple.performClick();
```